# Copying Range and ignoring blanks from all worksheets to 'Summary' Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, summary

I am in desperate need of help and have been racking my brain for a few days now.

Essentially, I am trying to create code (I am very new to VBA) that will go through all worksheets and copy these cells and/or ranges to a `Summary` Sheet. I need it to copy only when data exists, so I ignore any blanks.

The cells/ranges I want to copy across are:

```
B5
H10:H34 
H38:H49 
R37 
Q10:Q20
```

Essentially the data would be displayed as:

Client Name: `B5`

Products from Group A: `H10:H34` (ignoring blank cells)

Products from Group B: `H38:H49` (ignoring blank cells)

Online Service Requested: `R37`

External Services Selected: `Q10:Q20` (ignoring blank cells)

I have written code that will cycle through each worksheet but cannot seem to get it to work for the ranges and ignoring blank cells.

Could someone please help me? This is my code so far:

```
Sub Summary_All_Worksheets_With_Formulas()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Req As Worksheet
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    Dim RwNum As Long
    Dim basebook As Workbook
        With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Add a worksheet with the name "Requirements Gathering"
    Set basebook = ThisWorkbook
    Set Req = Worksheets("Requirements Gathering")
    'The links to the first sheet will start column 2
    ColNum = 1

    For Each Sh In basebook.Worksheets
        If Sh.Name <> Req.Name And Sh.Visible Then
            RwNum = 16
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
            Columns("C:C").Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

            'Copy the sheet name in the A column
            Req.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Value = Sh.Name
                For Each myCell In Sh.Range("B5,R37")
                RwNum = RwNum + 1
                Req.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _
                "='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & myCell.Address(False, False)
                Req.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"

                Next myCell
        End If

    Next Sh

    Req.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Then I want the data to display in the Summary sheet across the columns so sheet 1 data in column A sheet 2 in column B etc.

I know I am probably asking a hell of a lot but I just can't work this one out.

Super appreciation in advance for anyone who could help me.

Comment: Without an working copy its quite hard to provide you an good solution. Anyway your already on the right way. You should simply loop trough each range and inside if there is an value in the cell write it in your cell. That an simple `IF myCell.Value ..` Inside of it you set the value and only increase the `RwNum` if you done that.

Comment: Thank you Doomenik for the quick response. I tried this earlier but it didn't work. Could you give me an example for the 'IF myCell.Value' and how I could write that in?
For example, I am assuming it would be 'IF myCell.Value = vbNull' ? I am just not too familiar with VB yet so my understanding of loops is basic. So sorry :(

Comment: Hope this explains it good for you. Your VB is already not bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Summary_All_Worksheets_With_Formulas()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Req As Worksheet
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim ColNum As Integer
    Dim RwNum As Long
    Dim basebook As Workbook
        With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'Add a worksheet with the name "Requirements Gathering"
    Set basebook = ThisWorkbook
    Set Req = Worksheets("Requirements Gathering")
    'The links to the first sheet will start column 2
    ColNum = 1

    For Each Sh In basebook.Worksheets
        If Sh.Name <> Req.Name And Sh.Visible Then
            RwNum = 16
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
            Columns("C:C").Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

            'Copy the sheet name in the A column

            Req.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Value = Sh.Name
                For Each myCell In Sh.Range("B5,R37")
                  If myCell.Value <> "" Then

                    RwNum = RwNum + 1
                    Req.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _"='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & myCell.Address(False, False)
                    Req.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"

                    myCell.Copy 
                    'This stores an reference of the cell just like strg + c

                    Req.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats 
                    'This pastes the stored value, with the paste attribute xlPasteFormats it only paste the format not the value it self
                  End If
                Next myCell
        End If

    Next Sh

    Req.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I inserted the if like it should be, if you also want to check for 0 values you just have to write `OR <> 0`.

Anyway your code at the moment checks in every sheet for the same Range. This leeds to many unecessary loops. I would recomment to build a seperate loop for each sheet like:

```
If Sh.Name = "Products from Group A" Then
  Req.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Value = Sh.Name
  For Each myCell In Sh.Range("H38,H49")
    'Your Custom loop for Sheet
  Next myCell
End If
```

This seems like much unecessary code but it grants you much more possibilitys and avoid unecessary long loops. You could than do stuff like color the products from group a different than the ones from group b.

To separate it in rows it should look like this:

```
Sub Summary_All_Worksheets_With_Formulas()
        Dim Sh As Worksheet
        Dim Req As Worksheet
        Dim myCell As Range
        Dim ColNum As Integer
        Dim RwNum As Long
        Dim basebook As Workbook
            With Application
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

        'Add a worksheet with the name "Requirements Gathering"
        Set basebook = ThisWorkbook
        Set Req = Worksheets("Requirements Gathering")
        'The links to the first sheet will start column 2
        RwNum = 15 'We declare it in front of the loop to keep it. set here the first line your summary should start (Line it should start -1)

        For Each Sh In basebook.Worksheets
            If Sh.Name <> Req.Name And Sh.Visible Then
                ColNum = 2 'We reset it for each sheet to col2
                Columns("C:C").Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                RwNum = RwNum + 1 ' Every new Data Sheet we increase the row by 1 
                'Copy the sheet name in the A column

                Req.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Value = Sh.Name
                    For Each myCell In Sh.Range("B5,R37")
                      If myCell.Value <> "" Then

                        ColNum = ColNum + 1 'Here we now just increase the col for each entry it should fill 
                        Req.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).Formula = _"='" & Sh.Name & "'!" & myCell.Address(False, False)
                        Req.Cells.NumberFormat = "General"

                        myCell.Copy 
                        'This stores an reference of the cell just like strg + c

                        Req.Cells(RwNum, ColNum).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats 
                        'This pastes the stored value, with the paste attribute xlPasteFormats it only paste the format not the value it self
                      End If
                    Next myCell
            End If

        Next Sh

        Req.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
        With Application
            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
    End Sub
```

Eventually based on the amount of data you have to set `ColNum` as `Long` like you did with `RwNum`

Comment: Thanks so much Doomenik, I think I may have got it working just need one other thing. How can I get it to retain the formatting from the worksheet? example the font and colour used - is that even possible?

To your point about looking at the same range in every worksheet, this is exactly what I need the code to do as each worksheet will have data in those ranges (each sheet represents a customer)

Comment: @JaysonD Oh I tought the sheets represent the different categories, than your absolutly fine with your solution. I added how to copy the format in my solution. Just as an extra, with `xlPasteValues` you would also copy the Value it self. Just if you ever need it ;)

Comment: Hi @Doomenik - Sorry I had left the office. I've made the adjustments and it works beautifully, can't thank you enough. Just one small addition if I may? If I want the data to present across a row as opposed to down each column, how would I amend this? Just want to have options for presenting the data

Comment: @JaysonD normally you should open for new questions a new question :) But nothing to worry. If I understand you correctly you want to pivot the data. So instead of writing downwards writing it in columns. This should be easy, just dont increase the `RwNum` increase the  `ColNum`. If this is not what you meant please add an small example.

Comment: Thanks, I know I should have opened a new thread, thank you for accommodating. What I am asking is, the data comes back to the Summary Page and each sheet that is retrieved, has the specified ranges reported down the column, how can I get it to go across a row instead? So for example, each record (sheet) is displayed across a row as opposed to down a column? Hope that makes sense

Comment: @JaysonD If I understood it correctly my edit should do what you want

Comment: That's perfect, I can see now how you did it and just another thing I've learned. I really appreciate the time you have given this over the past 2 days mate - thank you very much.

Comment: @JaysonD No problem, we are here to help. If this is the correct answer for you, please mark it as accepted and upvote it. Oh and also upvote Tony´s answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can understand, this code does what you want in a simple way, at least in my testing. Hope it's helpful.

```
Option Explicit
Sub copyToSummarySheet()
Dim sumSh As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, i As Integer
Dim cell As Range, sumR As Range, sumCol As Integer
Dim r(1 To 5) As String
Set sumSh = Worksheets("sum")
r(1) = "B5"
r(2) = "H10:H34"
r(3) = "H38:H49"
r(4) = "R37"
r(5) = "Q10:Q20"
sumCol = 0
For Each sh In Worksheets
  Set sumR = sumSh.Range("A16")
  Set sumR = sumR.Offset(0, sumCol)
  If sh.Name <> sumSh.Name Then
    For i = 1 To 5
      For Each cell In sh.Range(r(i))
        If cell <> "" Then
          sumR = cell
          Set sumR = sumR.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
      Next cell
    Next i
    sumCol = sumCol + 1
  End If
Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tony - It does take the data but for some reason it's taking random data from fields/ranges not outlined in the r string (1 to 5). The solution I wrote with some tweaking from Doomenik seems to have resolved the issue. However, thank you very much for taking the time to assist in solving my problem, I truly appreciate these type of forums and people going out of their way to help !

Comment: When problems like you describe happen, I step through the code, line by line, often inserting temporary code such as 'cell.select' to pinpoint where the problem is. Figuring out mistakes like that is often the best way to learn.  In any event, thanks for your kind comment, and I'm glad you got the help you needed.